# How to force Facter to output in stable order?

Tags: puppet

If I run facter (e.g. facter -p) multiple times then every time I obtain the same results but in different order.

This makes more difficult than necessary to compare different runs of facter or puppet.

How can I obtain a stable output order?

Comment: What version of facter are you using?

Comment: I'm using Facter 2.4.6

Comment: Try with Facter 3+ - it is known to order results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Ruby are you using? In Ruby 1.8.7, hashes are not ordered

> The order in which you traverse a hash by either key or value may seem arbitrary, and will generally not be in the insertion order.

Which may be the cause of your problem?

Comment: Indeed I'm using ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

> How can I obtain a stable output order?

Facter has no command-line option for influencing the order of the output.  You can pipe it through `sort`, though, if you want to more easily compare results from different runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
facter | sort
```

run the result through sort